# Optimal order of csrf_meta_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails, my understanding is that we try to put stylesheets before javascript, and javascript near the end of the document to allow the DOM to fire faster.

Here's another question - where do tags go for optimum performance? My question is most specific to Rails' `csrf_meta_tag`. At the moment, I have a random assortment of orders - sometimes this tag is above CSS/JS, sometimes in the middle, sometimes below both. Any insight on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to keep your code clean an DRY. It is for you where to put your CSSs, Javascript and Meta tag.
But usually I do next way:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag ... %>
<%= javascript_include_tag ... %>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```